NES game- martial artist fights ghosts
I saw the ad for this in a comic book (possibly the comic adaptation of the first ninja turtles movie, I'm not sure), the ad showed a screenshot of a man dressed in what was meant to be clothed in the styles of either ancient China or Japan opposing mono-colored ghost figures. The blurb describing the game described fighting ghosts unarmed. Also the writing for the title, though English, was in a font suggestive of ancient Asian characters.

Do you remember if it had any screenshots? Were they in a forest? A building? Did he have a sword and/or throwing stars that he was throwing?

This sounds like Phantom Fighter, a NES game released in Japan in 1988 and the US in 1990. The cover art found on Wikipedia for the North American release matches your description pretty well:

According to the blurb on Wikipedia, you play as a "kung-fu master" and must fight through several towns filled with Jiangshi. Jiangshi are more like vampires than ghosts but they certainly look ghostly on the cover, and your character fights them with various unarmed martial arts moves.
Finally, the US release was April 1990, one month after the first Ninja Turtles movie, so it's entirely possible you saw an ad for Phantom Fighter in a comic adaptation of that movie.
